# Can I make a Call with NASL to run a C++ programm?

Tags: c++, scripting, nessus

We are working on a project with Nessus Attack Scripting Language ( NASL ) and we would like to run a programm written in C++. I want to ask, is it even possible to run another Script with NASL?

So we would like to run the NASL script, which runs another C++ programm, which works with Zigbee to mqtt.

Comment: Dies it matter that the other program was written in C++? Aren't you just asking about any executable?

Comment: Yes its matter, because we are working with a other library which is written in C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Not according to the manual. In fact it is specifically disallowed.

> **1.1**  What is NASL ?
>
> NASL is a scripting language designed for the Nessus security scanner. Its aim is to allow anyone to write a test for a given security hole in a few minutes, to allow people to share their tests without having to worry about their operating system, and to garantee everyone that a NASL script can not do anything nasty except performing a given security test against a given target.
> Thus, NASL allows you to easily forge IP packets, or to send regular packets. It provides you some convenient functions that will make the test of web and ftp server more easy to write. NASL garantees you that a NASL script :
>
> - will not send any packet to a host other than the target host
> - will not execute any commands on your local system

http://student.ing-steen.se/java/javacoding/toys/more_toys/nessus/txtfilez/nasl.html

Comment: So its not possible to run another script?

Comment: @LostJosh When it says *"will not execute any commands on your local system"*, that seems pretty definitive to me. No.